# Basis for a free abelian group of finite rank

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, free-groups, free-modules

My question is as follows:

Given a free abelian group $G$ of finite rank $n$, is it true that every linearly independent set of $n$ members of $G$ form a basis for $G$ (when $G$ is viewed as a $\mathbb Z$-module)? I know this is true in the case of vector spaces, but I was wondering if this is true more generally for free modules.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not even true for $n=1$.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to come up with an example to show myself. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: That shouldn't be difficult. How many free abelian groups of rank 1 do you know? Which elements form a linearly independent set (of 1 member of the group)?

Comment: So I can take $\mathbb Z$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module with basis $\{1\}$, then another LI set $\{2\}$ which is clearly not a basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out in the comments, this is not correct. However, you may prove that if $\{m_1,\dots,m_n\}$ are independent in $G$ and $H=\langle m_1,\dots,m_n\rangle$, then $G/H$ is a finite abelian group.